# Ignore parent php.ini settings for subdomains

Tags: php, apache, vps, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 Apache VPS that hosts my website. I setup my website to use a php.ini file. The file is located in, */var/www/my-site.com/php.ini*. Now I have a subdomain that is located in, */var/www/my-site.com/public_html/subsite/*

My issue is that I dont want my subdomain to inherit the settings from my normal sites php.ini fik=le. So currently my-site.com uses auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file which sets up the header, logo, footer... But I do not want this to happen on my subdomain.

What do I have to change so it does not do that?

I've tried a bunch of things, but what I have now is a file, */var/www/my-site.com/public_html/subsite/php.ini* that looks like this:

```
auto_prepend_file none
auto_append_file none
```

Thanks

Comment: put a new php.ini in the subdomain

Comment: I did, "what I have now is a file, /var/www/my-site.com/public_html/subsite/php.ini that looks like this:"